# Grails dynamic method call with variable parameter

Tags: grails

In Grails Controller: 
How can I call a dynamic method like `Domain.findByName(params.name)` and not `Domain.findByName("X")` ?

Comment: You can just write params.name - thats it!

Comment: ensure your parameter contains the correct value. e.g. println params as first statement in your controller actoin.

Comment: This question lacks clarity. Why does `Domain.findByName(params.name)` not work the same as `Domain.findByName("X")` if `assert params.name == "X"`. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check out some [Grails Turorials](http://www.grails.org/Tutorials) and more specifically how the grails form tag works [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/form.html)!  You'll need to understand how the basic flow of the MVC model works to enjoy the power of Grails!  Take some time to learn this or you just lost and frustrated.

In your example the `params.name` will usually be filled by a form post using an input tag like [g:textField](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/textField.html).

If you want to see what values are included params object for a specific controller call you could do something like ....

```
class IceCreamController{

   def eatMoreIceCream = {
       println("the params are ${params}"); //<-- prints a Map of the values to the stdout

       if (!params.name){
           redirect(action:"showError",params:[message:"You have no name!"])
       }else{
           def iceCream = IceCream.findByName(params.name)

           if (iceCream){
              redirect(action:"showIceCream",params:[id:iceCream.id])
           }else{
               redirect(action:"showError",params:[message:"no ice cream for name ${params.name}."])
           }

       }

   }

}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

The params.name gets its value from a web call like ../book/findAuthor?name="Odyssey". If in the findAuthor method, inside a bookControler execute the ... book.findByName("Odyssey") it returns the author, but not if execute the book.findByName(params.name)! I tryed also the book.findByName("$params.name")!

Comment: do a println(params.name) to see what the value is.

Comment: I did it. The params.name has the expected value!

Comment: You may have to provide some additional information for me to help.  Could you show your domain class controller method and .gsp in your question?

Comment: class Book {
    String  title
    String  author
    
    static constraints = {
    }
}
BookController
def findByTitle = {
        println params
        println "Title = $params.Title"
        def book1 =  Book.findByTitle("Ilias")        
        def book2 =  Book.findByTitle("$params.Title")
        println "Result1 = $book1.author" 
        println "Result2 = $book2.author" 
 }
[Title:"Ilias", action:findByTitle, controller:book]
Title = "Ilias"
Result1 = Homer
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request:[GET]/TestIdeas/book/findByTitle-parameters:

Comment: way are you wrapping the params.Title in "$"?